# "Страница загружена" на js

Tags: javascript

Как на javascript прописать условие, что страница загружена без использования jQuery?

Answer (score 2):

Вот это чудо Кроссбраузерное событие [onDOMContentLoaded или onReady](http://javascript.ru/tutorial/events/ondomcontentloaded)

Подключаете этот скрипт на страницу и пишите `onReady(function(){});`

Answer (score 2):

Есть [интересное решение](http://studioad.ru/blog/2009-04-13-65) на studioad.

Comment: да очень интересное решение и кода совсем немного, спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Поместить JS код внизу страницы. Или создать обработчик для `<body onload="function();">`
Где функция, это Вывод Вашего сообщения

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял задачу, то проверить, используется ли на странице jquery, можно как-то так:

```
if(!$()) console.log("whithout jquery")
else console.log("jquery version - "+$().jquery)
```

Comment: Неверно. `!$()` - вызов несуществующей функции же. И вообще, ты задачу всё-таки неправильно понял.